# Как сделать так чтобы главный поток завершал свою работу после побочных?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Я вызываю в main потоке 10 побочных потоков, хочу чтобы main поток завершил свою работу после побочных и вывел сообщение о конце работы. Я решил сделать это с помощью методов isAlive и join, но ничего не получилось и код работает через раз.

```
for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            sideStream = new Printer(i);
            thread = new Thread(sideStream);
            thread.start();
        }


        if(thread.isAlive())
        {
            try{
                thread.join();
            }catch(InterruptedException ignored){}
        }
        System.out.println("End...");
```

Comment: если убрать `if(thread.isAlive())` то лучше станет?

Comment: ничего не поменялось если честно, но как минимум я понял что это условие мне в тако интерпретации ничего не дает

Comment: стоп, вы в цикле создаете потоки, но при это потоки перезаписываете в одну и ту же переменную? Сохраните потоки в какой нить ArrayList или массив и потом по нему ходите и на каждом вызваайте join

Comment: Большое спасибо, это было очевидное замечание и оно мне очень помогло решить проблему!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы в цикле создаете потоки, но при это потоки перезаписываете в одну и ту же переменную. Сохраните потоки в какой-нибудь ArrayList или массив и потом по нему ходите и на каждом вызывайте join.

Answer (score 2):

Отдельный цикл создаёт нитки, запоминает и запускает их:

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[10];
for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; ++i) {
    threads[i] = new Thread(new Printer(i + 1));
    threads[i].start();
}
```

Отдельный цикл ждёт окончания всех ниток:

```
for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; ++i) {
    try {
        threads[i].join();
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
    }
}
```